# How to migrate Excel Add-in into Smartview

Tags: hyperion, essbase, smartview

I want to migrate excel addin into smartview but not able to do it . please help me.

Comment: Actually, I don't have any idea about it....This task is assigned to us for practice purpose.

Comment: Till now I tried with opening excel developer section -<visual basic editor. but not finding the exact solution

Comment: This question is still unanswerable because it's too vague. There is no migration from the classic add-in into Smart View. They are two different pieces of software. If you had previously used the classic Excel add-in but now needed to use Smart View, you'd have to install Smart View, configure your Smart View provider, connect to Essbase, then use the Smart View add-in to perform your Essbase operations such retrieving, zooming in, and more.